# Jquery draggable error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have forked an example on jsfiddle that has tabs on a dialog box http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/dNyYQ/ and i made a few changes.First,i added a title bar, http://jsfiddle.net/wwDpD/1/ and then set draggable to true http://jsfiddle.net/wzF5Y/2/

The final fiddle surprisingly works on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wzF5Y/2/ but when i run the example of my browser FF 12.0,the dialog is hidden above the top most div;that is above the open dialog button.

What could i be missing?.

Image:
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the dialog (as well as the overlay) is being constrained to the `div` with `id="force"`. Firefox tries to keep the dimensions of the `div` as small as possible given the size of its child elements. Thus, when you try to drag the dialog, it gets pushed up inside the force `div`, since the `div` only covers the top of the page. In the other browsers, the dimensions of the force `div` are maximized, so you can drag the dialog anywhere on the page. You can get the same behavior as with other browsers by adding the following CSS:

```
#force {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to set the z-index of the dialog.
Also, if you can post a snapshot of what you see in FF that will be great.